# RavenDb Transform Can not convert string to null

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have created the following index:

```
public class LawDisadvantagesForListIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<LawDisadvantage, LawDisadvantagesForListIndex.IndexResult>
{
    public class IndexResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public long Rating { get; set; }
   }

    public class LawDisadvantageForList
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public long Rating { get; set; }
        public long CommentsCount { get; set; }
    }

    public LawDisadvantagesForListIndex()
    {
        Map = lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                  from vote in lawDisadvantage.Votes
                                  select new {Id = lawDisadvantage.Id, Rating = vote.Value};

        Reduce = (lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                      group lawDisadvantage by lawDisadvantage.Id
                                      into agg
                                      select new
                                                 {
                                                     Id = agg.Key,
                                                     Rating = agg.Sum(x => x.Rating)
                                                 });

        TransformResults = (database, indexResults) => from indexResult in indexResults
                                                       let lawDisadvantage = database.Load<LawDisadvantage>(indexResult.Id)
                                                       select new
                                                                  {
                                                                      Id = lawDisadvantage.Id,
                                                                      Rating = indexResult.Rating,
                                                                      CommentsCount = lawDisadvantage.Comments.Count
                                                                  };
    }
}
```

So I take LawDisadvantage document, process it by MapReduce and then add some additional fields by transforming. But as result I get exception message "System.InvalidOperationException: The transform results function failed. Doc '', Error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'long'". The exception source is "indexResult.Rating" clause.

By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863283/ravendb-indexing-errors) question looks relevant.

**Update.** I have updated to last unstable version - it is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The casting you needed to do in indexes has long been an annoying issue in RavenDB. Behind the scenes the index your write gets converted from text into code. However, to make it flexible (schema-less) it works using dynamic types, but there's a fair bit of casting that needs to take place.

Having said all that, the code recently got an overhaul and so these issue won't show up anymore, see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/a3f118f56e0c41) for more info.